# External Javascript File - QueryString Info Available?

Tags: javascript, query-string

On an HTML page I have a reference to an external Javascript file like this:

```
<script src="http://MyServer.com/js/myscript.js?Happy=True"></script>
```

Inside the **myscript.js** when it runs, can I get the **Happy=True** QueryString-like part of the js source URL?

Note I do not want the URL of the HTML page, I need to get the URL of the js file.

My Guess is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be able to detect the src-attribute of the script-element(would be easier to locate  if the `<script>` has an ID). Out of that URL you could extract the Query-String.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but it seems (at least in Chrome) that the querystring gets stripped away. Not even `getAttribute` would get it. Just tested Firefox too. Same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/8G2Dm/1/

Comment: Mmmh, I get the full path including the Query-String in Chrome(but it's V5, I think I'll need to update sometimes ^^)

Comment: ...scratch that. Perhaps a jsFiddle issue? When I test locally, it works. +1

Comment: You need to access `getElementsByTagName('script')[2]` on jsfiddle, there are more scripts on jsfiddle embedded, the reported name is `dummy.js`, not `myscript.js` like expected.